# Concatenate Two strings in HTML in client side(No Server)

Tags: javascript, html

Can I concatenate two strings in HTML?

I want to achieve the following functionality-

```
<a href="#"+"javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id">go to the 1st DIV tag.</a>
```

It could have been done using `document.write()` in javascript but I want to know if there is any **concatenation functionality in HTML itself**.

Comment: HTML is a markup language. No, it has no 'concatenation functionality'.

Comment: As far as I not. By the way it doesn't matter because your code will never work.

Comment: Hypothetically if you could (you can't), what are you actually trying to achieve by using `#` together with JS?

Comment: @nnnnnn, # along with the `id` of an element is used for linking to that element in the body of the page itself.

Comment: @Rajesh your statement is complete wrong. See last answers for a correct statement

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to prompt you to ask the _real_ question. If it is "Can HTML concatenate two arbitrary strings?" then "No". If it is "Can I implement a link that jumps to the first div on the page without hardcoding the div's id?" then "Yes".

Comment: @reporter - Rajesh's statement in the comment above is completely correct. `<a href="#abc">` lets the link jump to the element with id `abc`. That's what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: I had never seen and used this statement before.

Comment: I just wanted to know the fact regarding HTML. There are many ways to achieve it as your answers say but no way to do it with HTML alone.

Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there isn't.
HTML is markup, it is not turing complete.

Answer (score 4):

One (primitive) way to achieve this with JavaScript would be

```
<a href="#"
  onclick="window.location.hash='#'+document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id; return false;">
  go to the 1st DIV tag.
</a>
```

But since those links are useless when JS is not available, they should probably only be *generated* by JS in the first place.

Comment: +1, you saved me from having to type the same answer. `onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].scrollIntoView();"` should achieve a similar effect with less code.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. HTML is markup.
You should use dynamic HTML and JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by using this.href in java script

```
<a href="#" onload="this.href=this.href+document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id;" >
```

ex

```
<a href="targetWithInDoc.html" onload="this.href=this.href+'#block1';" >block 1</a>
```

Comment: Do anchor elements have an `onload` event?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in the way you're attempting, but if JavaScript is running on the client anyway then you can still achieve the functionality you're looking for.  You just need to separate the tag from the script:

```
<a href="#" id="someID">Go to the first DIV tag</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('someID').href = '#' + document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it wont help u now but I'm posting this for others who will come to this question by searching

we can achieve it this way :

`<a href='<%#String.Concat("string1", "string2")%>'></a>`